# re.compile only takes two arguments, is there a way to make it take more? Or another way around that?

Tags: python, screen-scraping, enumerate

I am able to access an email in txt file form on my computer, and now my goal is to scrape specific data out of it. I have utilized `re.compile` and `enumerate` to parse through the email looking for matching words (in my case, fish species such as GOM Cod), and then printing them. But there are 100's more emails I will need to parse thru, each with several different fish species listed in them....so my question is: what is the best way to go about this? I can't put all 17 different possible fish species into one `re.compile` function so should I just have 17 different blocks of the same code with just the fish species changed in each? Is that the most efficient way? My code is below.

```
import os
import email
import re

path = 'Z:\\folderwithemail'

for filename in os.listdir(path):
file_path = os.path.join(path, filename)
if os.path.isfile(file_path):
    with open(file_path, 'r') as f:
        sector_result = []
        pattern = re.compile("GOM Cod", re.IGNORECASE)
        for linenum, line in enumerate(f):
            if pattern.search(line) != None:
                sector_result.append((linenum, line.rstrip('\n')))
                for linenum, line in sector_result:
                    print ("Fish Species:", line)
```

Comment: "I can't put all 17 different possible fish species into one re.compile function"? Why not? That's what alternation is for...

Comment: Can you not make your regex `GOM Cod|Halibut|Trout|...`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can *alternate* between fish species using the vertical bar `|`:

> `A|B`, where A and B can be arbitrary REs, creates a regular expression
>   that will match either A or B

```
pattern = re.compile(r"GOM Cod|Salmon|Tuna", re.IGNORECASE)
```

Comment: That worked perfectly thanks. I'm very new to Python so I figured it was a simple fix. But can I ask why it prints the GOM Cod line twice when I run it?

    `Fish Species: up to 4,000 lbs live wt GOM cod @ 1.40 lbs`
    `Fish Species: up to 4,000 lbs live wt GOM cod @ 1.40 lbs`
    `Fish Species: 2,000 lbs American plaice @ .45 lbs`

Comment: @StephenM There are two different emails containing that fish name?

Comment: Well the thing is that I'm directing to a folder that has only one email in it, that way I can get this code down pat before I parse 100's at a time. And there is only one line in the email that mentions GOM Cod so I was thinking it must be something wrong with the code.